# How to wait for elasticsearch helpers.reindex to finish in Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-helpers

I'm reindexing a big index and need to delete the old index in order to add an alias to the new index.

```
helpers.reindex(client=es, source_index=index_old, target_index=index_new, )

# those 2 need to run when reindex finishes
es.indices.delete(index=index_old)
es.indices.put_alias(index=index_new, name=index_old)
```

The problem is that last 2 commands need to wait for reindex to finish, otherwise it will delete the original index and will not work.

I see elasticsearch has refresh=wait_for but not for python helpers.reindex.

What approach would be ok to make the reindex syncronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As documentation stats, helpers.reindex is deprecated, and main API reindex is preferred.
2. reindex method contains `wait_for_completion` param which is true by default, so by default `Elasticsearch().reindex(...)` is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this `helpers.reindex(client=es, source_index=index_old, target_index=index_new, )` to this `helpers.reindex(client=es, source_index=index_old, target_index=index_new, bulk_kwargs={'wait_for_completion': True} )`

Not tested.